# cannot found icon app after installed on emulator

Tags: android, apk

I installed the file apk on emulator, but I cannot find icon application on screen emulator.
I do not understand why it appears in application manager without on screen emulator.
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/DlsuQasA2uxHKFFBJI9abrBi38fich6Ap_sgzQQyqSs=w381-h512

Comment: please post your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified the following pointed out components in the `android manifest` of your android project,
**android:label** in the application tag is the one for setting your application's icon,and do specify the activity you want to start on the click of the application's icon from home screen as `launcher` as in the image

[image]

Comment: my manifest here: 
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>
i resolved it, tks so much

Comment: if this resolved your issue than you can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The main activity for your app must be declared in the manifest with an  that includes the MAIN action and LAUNCHER category. For example:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```